# load a expression from another one

Tags: angularjs

Is there any directive or way to load a scope expression from another expression?

Suppose we have

```
$scope.find = 'a_expression';
$scope.a_expression = 'found';
```

How could we do something like that?

```
{{ {{ find }} }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{$eval(find)}}`

That would do it.